# Where is the keystone virtual configuration file in Devstack?

Tags: openstack, devstack, keystone, federation

Where is the file `wsgi-keystone.conf` located in the Devstack env?
I am trying to configure federation.

I only can see this file:

```
keystone-wsgi-public.conf
```

Which contains:

```
ProxyPass "/identity" "unix:/var/run/uwsgi/keystone-wsgi-public.socket|uwsgi://uwsgi-uds-keystone-wsgi-public/" retry=0
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you have `/etc/keystone/keystone-uwsgi-public.ini` ?